# Examine object value between fluent interface calls

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-debugging, fluent-interface

Imagine this call which uses three fluent API's to make a very simple and readable function (the IQueryable `Where` and `OrderBy`, the AutoMapper `Project` and `To`, and `ToDataSourceResult` from Kendo).

```
Return Json(DataSource.TemplateItems.Where(Function(x) x.TemplateID= id) _
                                    .OrderBy(Function(x) x.SortOrder) _
                                    .Project() _
                                    .To(Of TemplateIdRowViewModel) _
                                    .ToDataSourceResult(req))
```

For debugging, I sometimes want to examine the current value being passed around *in between* calls to the fluent API.  For example, I might want to know what my `IQueryable` looks like after `Project` and `To` finish with it but before `ToDataSourceResult` gets it.

I'm using the VS 2010 debugger.  Right now I find myself editing the call to include temporary variable for each step so I can examine them, like this:

```
Dim where = DataSource.TemplateItems.Where(Function(x) x.TemplateID = id)
Dim ordered = where.OrderBy(Function(x) x.SortOrder)
Dim projected = ordered.Project().To(Of TemplateIdRowViewModel)()
Dim result = projected.ToDataSourceResult(req)
Dim jsonified = Json(result)

Return jsonified
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Project().To<>() !